# Quotation marks are seemingly dropped in the Terraform startup script

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-compute-engine, terraform-provider-gcp

I build a cluster on Google Cloud Platform using Terraform. I need to execute a set of parametrised commands during build phase of the virtual machine, so I use a startup script (metadata_startup_script) parametrised using the templatefile method.

For simpler tasks, it worked like a charm. However, now I try to run a command with strings surrounded by quotes like:
`foo --parameter=value --but-also="Value with spaces"`

I noticed that it did not make any effect and the commands following it were not executed at all.

I checked the log of the startup script execution via:
`sudo journalctl -u google-startup-scripts.service`

My command was presented as:
`COMMAND=/usr/bin/foo --parameter=value --but-also=Value with spaces`
It looked like the quotations were stripped and it resulted in the failure of the command.

I tried various solution like passing the variables surrounded by other quotation marks inside the script (template file):
`foo --parameter='${value} --but-also='${another_value}'`

Another solution I tries was surrounding the parameters to the templatefile at a higher level like:

```
metadata_startup_script = templatefile("sh/my_setup.sh", {
    ...
    another_value = "${var.another_value}",
    ...
  })
```

or escaping them:

```
metadata_startup_script = templatefile("sh/my_setup.sh", {
    ...
    another_value = "\"${var.another_value}\"",
    ...
  })
```

Unfortunately none of that solved my problem.

How should I properly pass such arguments?

Edit:
Not to clutter the generalized part of the post, I attach part of my file. I would be too long in its entirety, but this snippet should be sufficient.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Non-parametrized commands
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y upgrade 
sudo apt-get -y install python3 lvm2

# ...

# Commands with simple positional parameters (these work)
sudo cephadm bootstrap --mon-ip ${mon_ip} --ssh-user ${ceph_username} 
sudo ceph fs volume create ${cephfs_name}
sudo ceph fs authorize ${cephfs_name} client.${ceph_client_username} / rw | sudo tee ${filesystem_key_dir}/${filesystem_key_name}

# Problematic command
sudo radosgw-admin user create --subuser=${rgw_username} --uid=${rgw_uid} --display-name=${rgw_user_display_name} --key-type=swift --secret=${rgw_secret} --access=full

# Subsequent commands (these will not execute, unless I comment out the problematic one)
gcloud storage cp ${config_file_dir}/${config_file_name} gs://${bucket_name}/
```

Comment: Can you actually show example of `metadata_startup_script` in your TF code?

Comment: Where in this script is `another_value`?

Comment: @Marcin I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. If you ask which values in the example should be surrounded by the quotation marks, that would be every value from the "Problematic command". rgw_user_display_name to name one. `--display-name="A name"` instead of `--display-name=A name` after substitution.

Comment: In the question you wrote that you use `another_value = "\"${var.another_value}\"",`? So where exactly is `another_value` used in your `sh/my_setup.sh`?

Comment: @Marcin However, if you ask about where these values are defined, they are mostly located in locals, so for example `rgw_username = "user:subuser"` and `rgw_username = local.rgw_username` in the templatefile argument. The exception is `secret`, which is created by a `random_password` resource. Ultimately the templatefile method substitutes the values. I hope this answers your question.

Comment: @Marcin If you ask specifically about the entity "another_value", it does not exist. It was meant to represent any value from the "Problematic command" as I expect each of them to look like `this="Value"`instead of `this=Value` after substitution.

Comment: Sorry, your question is confusing. It would be better to edit it to show what is your actual real code (without some non-existing variables), what are real errors that you get. Also what is the current outcome exactly, and what do you expect to achieve.